# For good style, should you surround a mathemtical operator with a space when it's inside as an argument?

Tags: python, styles

I read [PEP 8: Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and I wasn't quite sure how to style mathematical operators inside arguments.

For example, for the `=` sign PEP 8 says

```
Yes:
    x = 3
    y = foo(bar=3)
No:
    x=3
    y = foo(bar = 3)
```

But what about other mathematical operators like `-`, `+`, `/`, etc. Which is good style?

```
foo_bar = bar[i - 3][j + 2]
z = foobar(y=i - 1, z=k + 2)
```

or

```
foo_bar = bar[i-3][j+1]
z = foobar(y=i-1, z=k+2)
```

?

To be honest, the latter looks better in my opinion.

**From PEP 8:**

Other Recommendations

- Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not).
- Use spaces around arithmetic operators:
- Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right up at the top of Pep 8 is this advice:

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.

There are two exceptions made explicit, and I think argument passing falls under this:

> 1. When applying the rule would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows the rules.

I'd leave out the spaces in the arguments, making your example:

```
foo_bar = bar[i - 3][j + 2]
z = foobar(y=i-1, z=k+2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Operators should always be surrounded by spaces. `=` when used for keyword arguments is not considered an operator.

Comment: So you're saying do `foo_bar = bar[i - 3][j + 2]` and `z = foobar(y=i - 1, z=k + 2)`?

Comment: Man, that looks weird (the `foobar(y=i - 1, z=k + 2)`), but I'll get used to it lol.

Comment: What about `:`? Do `a[:-1]` or `a[: -1]`?

Comment: `:` used to slice is not an operator.

Comment: If you look at the [list comprehension doc](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), they write `squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]`. No spaces around `**`. Also they write `for x in [1,2,3]:`. No spaces even after a comma in a list lol.